# Buffer to have ( 5V-->15V) with DAC conversion

Tags: buffer

I'm working on a project of a digital control of a DC/DC converter (DC/DC converter which I need to control with an FPGA). My DC/DC(IGBT) is wired to an ARCAL 2610 driver.

My question is:

My FPGA(DE2 board) has a 5V output but the driver has a 15V input, I know that I need to put a buffer between them (I chose a hex buffer for the simultaneous DAC conversion) but do I need to add an amplifier to get a 15V output for the driver or will the buffer do it in the same time?

Buffer: Texas Instrument CD4049UB

Comment: Have you though of separating the logic and the power?

Comment: what do you meen by separating the logic and the power? and sorry for my weaky english !!! I speak french

Comment: The power stage should be powered with 15V, while the control is using 5V.

Comment: the FPGA card is supplied by a 9V and give a 5V output ,And the driver is 15V supplied and need a 15V input!!

Comment: And you will need to supply that 15V, you don't have choice, right? And no amplifier will do it for you. You need a separate power supply or DC/DC converter for it.

Comment: My aim at the end is to control a DC/DC converter by the driver? I don't know If I'm clear enough?

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "control DC/DC" ? Setting its output voltage? Anything else?

Comment: it's the chopper (boost or buck )

Answer (score 1):

You can power the CD4049 from 15V and directly drive into the power stage, but you will still need voltage translation from the 5V domain to the 15V domain prior to hitting the input of the 4049 since you would not be able to overcome the Vih of the 15V 4049.  A transistor + resistor may be able to work for your application as the voltage translation stage pending how quickly you need to switch.

Something like this?

[image: 5V-to-15V digital conversion]

Comment: I have 15V supply and I can use it for the CD4049 and also for the driver but how can I have 15V at the output ( I don't know the gain of the buffer?) if it has a gain of 3 it will be ok!!

Comment: The CD4049 is a digital CMOS hex inverter.  It does not have gain in the way you are probably thinking of.  When you put a voltage in above Vih, it outputs a voltage below Vol.  Likewise, when you put a voltage in below Vil, it outputs a voltage above Voh.  Your signal input to this IC must already be 0-15V if you power it from 15V.

Comment: that means that i need to put opAmp after the buffer? to pass from 5V to 15V

Comment: but the buffer is necessary for the DAC conversion ( is that the MOS on your diagram?